# XCTest test fails with test case "did not finish" when I NSLog from the test case

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Just starting to work with XCTest in Xcode 5 ( (Xcode Version 5.0.2 [5A3005]). I made a sample test file where I test that true is true. It works and the test passes as expected. When I add an `NSLog` statement in front of the assertion, the test fails with a message "test_case did not finish" where "test_case" is my test method name (testTrue in my case).

Here's `test1.m` in the failing case. The only difference between failing and working is that the failing case has an `NSLog` in the test method. (It also fails when I try to `NSLog` in the setUp and/or tearDown methods.)

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface test1 : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation test1

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here; it will be run once, before the first test case.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here; it will be run once, after the last test case.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testTrue
{
    // if I comment out following NSLog the test works
    NSLog(@"test1: testTrue");
    XCTAssertTrue(true, @"true is not true");
}

@end
```

Here's the specific output from the Log Navigator in the failure case:

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-02-07 21:31:42 +0000
Test Suite 'xct-test1Tests.xctest' started at 2014-02-07 21:31:42 +0000
Test Suite 'test1' started at 2014-02-07 21:31:42 +0000
Test Case '-[test1 testTrue]' started.
testTrue did not finish
```

Here's the same output when it works (when I don't include the `NSLog` statement):

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000
Test Suite 'xct-test1Tests.xctest' started at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000
Test Suite 'test1' started at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000
Test Case '-[test1 testTrue]' started.
Test Case '-[test1 testTrue]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Suite 'test1' finished at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'xct-test1Tests.xctest' finished at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-02-07 21:38:59 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
```

So why does this test fail when I `NSLog` in it? Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Does this happen when you change the string your are nslogging?

Comment: Sulthan - It does not matter what string I log. It happens in all cases.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on the NSLog call and stepping through the test?